# I read this story about a physical assault. How much of it actually makes sense?

Tags: criminal-law, rules-of-court, court, assault

I read this story about an assault, and I'm wondering if it adds up or not.

So these two guys get into an argument, and it gets really out of hand, causing one of the guys to tackle the other guy and repeatedly punch him in the face. The attacker stops, and shortly afterward the police arrive and arrest the attacker.

The victim gets subpoenaed to court a few months later as the only other witness besides the attacker himself to the assault, as the police arrived after the attacker had already stopped beating the victim up.

The attacker is being charged with attempted murder. However, when the victim is called to the stand, he testifies that the attacker wasn't trying to kill him, the argument just got really out of hand, and the attacker was only trying to scare the victim to shut him up for a little while.

After hearing the victim's testimony, the judge reduces the charges of attempted murder to physical assault. The attacker is sentenced to six months in jail, but winds up getting out on good behavior.

Does any of that make sense?

Neither the victim nor the attacker went to a hospital after the assault. There was a lot of scurrying around after the attacker tackled the victim, so they both had scratches/bruises from that. The wounds the victim had from being punched healed on their own time, as they weren't really that serious, as it was a very messy attack.

So is it possible for the victim's testimony to reduce the charges of attempted murder all the way down to physical assault?

Is six months an appropriate amount of time for jail time for physical assault? Is it too short/long?

Also, would the attacker be able to get out of jail early on good behavior or is that not possible here?

Does everything else about the story add up or are there other things about it that are incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same question was asked elsewhere a few days ago. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41209/i-just-read-this-story-about-a-lawsuit-does-it-make-any-sense